# Failed to ssh to machine after installing Docker

Tags: networking, ssh

My ssh stops working after I successfully installed Docker (following the official site instruction https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/) on an ubuntu machine `A`. Now my laptop cannot ssh to `A` but ok for other machines, say `B`, that sitting in the same network environment as `A`. `A` can ssh to `B` and `B` can also ssh to `A`. What could be the problem? Can anyone suggest how I can make a diagnostic?

Comment: What is the error message you get? Can you see if the ssh port is open? Try also with `ssh -vv <your_host>` to obtain more info.

Comment: OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <my_host> [<my_host_ip>] port 22.
ssh: connect to host <my_host> port 22: Operation timed out

Comment: Any idea about this :( ?

Comment: Try this : http://www.unixlore.net/articles/troubleshooting-ssh-connections.html and edit your question if you have more useful information.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a vpn service you might be encountering an ip conflict between docker0 interface and your vpn service.
to resolve this:

stop docker service:

```
sudo service docker stop
```

remove old docker0 interface created by docker

```
ip link del docker0
```

[configure docker0 bridge](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/) (in my case i only had to define "bip" option)

start the docker service:

```
sudo service docker start
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there is ip conflict between docker0 interface and your VPN service. As already answered, way is to stop docker service, remove docker0 interface and configure daemon.json file. I added following lines to my daemon.json

```
 {
 "default-address-pools":
     [
         {"base":"10.10.0.0/16","size":24}
     ]
}
```

My VPN was providing me an IP like 192.168.*.* so I chose a base IP that does not fall in that range. Note that the daemon.json file does not exist, so you have to create it in, etc/docker/.